# SESSION Loop that increments counter

Tags: php

My session checks if a user is logged , however when I refresh the page the session test runs again and starts to execute the code which then adds +1 to the members online counter everytime . I would like my code to check if the session is true like below but not if I refresh the page or navigate to another page .(Only Once per login) How can this be possible ?

PS MY code is not secure My code is not in any live environment , Security will be applied later to prevent sql injection .

```
 include('..\db.php');
    $con = mysqli_connect($dbsrvname, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $dbname);
    $guest_timeout = time() -1 * 60;
    $member_timeout = time() -2 * 60;
    $guest_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $time = time()

    // This session check adds +1 to my member online counter when page is reloaded
    if(isset($_SESSION['CurrentUser'])){

        //if user is logged
        $sqlt = mysqli_query($con,"DELETE * FROM active_guests WHERE guest_ip='".$guest_ip."'");
        $sqlt2 = mysqli_query($con,"REPLACE INTO active_members VALUES ('".$_SESSION['CurrentUser']."','".$time."')");

    }else{

        //if user not logged
        $sqlt3 = mysqli_query($con,"REPLACE INTO active_guest (guest_ip,time_visited)VALUES ('".$guest_ip."','".$time."')");

    }
    $sqlt4 = mysqli_query($con,"DELETE * FROM  active_guest WHERE time_visited < ".$guest_timeout);
    $sqlt5 = mysqli_query($con,"DELETE * FROM  active_members WHERE time_visited < ".$member_timeout);
    $sqlt6 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT guest_ip FROM active_guests");
    $online_guests = mysqli_num_rows($sqlt6);
    $sqlt7 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT username FROM active_members");
    $online_members = mysqli_num_rows($sqlt7);
    ?>

    <div class="container">
    <p>online Guests : <?php echo $online_guests ; ?></p>
    <p>online Members : <?php echo $online_members ; ?></p>
    </div>
```

Comment: I don't understand "When I refresh the page the session test becomes true again". Isn't it supposed to be true if they're logged in? Where is it adding 1 to the online counter?

Comment: The session is true as the user is logged in , however when I refresh the page the session checks and executes the code again , The counter adds +1 when it adds the username to the database ,  $sqlt2 = mysqli_query($con,"REPLACE INTO active_members VALUES ('".$_SESSION['CurrentUser']."','".$time."')");
$online_members = mysqli_num_rows($sqlt7); each time

Comment: Is there a unique key on the username column of `active_members`?

Comment: When you use `REPLACE INTO`, it will overwrite the row if there's a unique index on the `username` column. But if there's no unique index, it adds a new row with a duplicate username.

Comment: Okay that sounds like its the issue as it does duplicate , I don't have a unique key  assigned I will look into this . Thanks .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a unique index on the `username` column so that `REPLACE` will replace instead of inserting a duplicate row.

```
ALTER TABLE active_members ADD UNIQUE INDEX (username);
```

You probably also need a unique index on the `guest_ip` column of `active_guests`, although it's possible that multiple users could be coming from the same IP.

Comment: Perfect , Excellent advice and I certainly will implement . Many Thanks